# Merge 70 netCDF files with xarray

Tags: python, netcdf, python-xarray

I want to merge 70 netCDF files into one. For that I use the .to_netcdf() function of xarray:

```py
    ds = xarray.open_mfdataset('*.nc')
    ds.to_netcdf('SST_2021-10_timeseries.nc')
```

My problem is that my jupyter notebook always hangs up because the number of files is too high. Is there a more efficient way to merge the files?

Comment: Not an answer with netCDF, but another option would be to use a zarr store rather than netCDF (e.g. [`ds.to_zarr`](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.Dataset.to_zarr.html)), as zarr has chunking support and parallel writes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative would be to use nctoolkit. Commands would be as follows:

```
import nctoolkit as nc
ds = nc.open_data('*.nc')
ds.merge("time")
ds.to_nc('SST_2021-10_timeseries.nc')
```

Or you could do it on the command line with CDO:

```
cdo -mergetime *.nc SST_2021-10_timeseries.nc
```

Those options should get around any RAM issues.

Comment: Seems like I can't open all datasets with the asterix in this line: ds = nc.open_data('*.nc') Will get then the message that there is no dataset with the name *.nc

Comment: Which version of nctoolkit have you installed? Conda has a tendency to install an old version, so the version you have may not accept wild cards

Comment: nctoolkit-0.3.9, I think that's the latest, right?

Comment: OK. That should work. But try: `ds = nc.open_data(nc.create_ensemble(".", recursive = False))`. What OS are you using?

Comment: though the string "*.nc" should replaced be `glob.glob("'.nc')` by nctoolkit (line 436: https://github.com/pmlmodelling/nctoolkit/blob/master/nctoolkit/api.py). So I'm puzzled by what's going on